# Почему Postgres не требует пароль при входе без sudo?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Я задал пользователю пароль используя синтаксис:

```
postgres=# alter user pavel with password '1';
ALTER ROLE

 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 pavel     | Create role, Create DB                                     | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}


 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls |               passwd                | valuntil | useconfig 
----------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------
 postgres |       10 | t           | t        | t       | t            | md521.............................. |          | 
 pavel    |    18066 | t           | f        | f       | f            | md58f.............................. |          |
```

Но когда я вхожу под ролью `pavel`

```
$ psql -U pavel postgres
```

Пароль у меня не запрашивается.

Почему postgres не спрашивает у меня пароль хотя `sudo` я не использую? Какие могут быть причины? (все это работает под linux).

`pg_hba.conf`

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Что в файле `pg_hba.conf`? Может там метод `trust` прописан для вашего пользователя или хоста? А файла `.pgpass` в корне домашней директории нет?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev `.pgpass` не нашел а в `pg_hba.conf` там куча всего добавил в вопрос то что мне показалось относится к вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Клиент psql не станет просить вводить пароль, если он сам пароль уже знает (`.pgpass`, если существует) либо если сам сервер не запрашивает передачу пароля.

Что и когда запрашивает сервер описывается в `pg_hba.conf`, правила проверяются по порядку сверху вниз. И ещё важный момент - без указания ключа `-h` (hostname) psql будет пытаться подключиться через unix-сокет.

В вашем pg_hba.conf первое правило

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

неприменимо, т.к. вы пытаетесь подключиться не как пользователь postgres. Зато следующее правило:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Описывает как раз подходящий случай, подключение local - т.е. по unix-сокету, любой пользователь и любая база. Указана проверка подлинности типа `peer`. Эта проверка не использует пароль, вместо этого проверяется, что пользователь unix выполняющий подключение к базе равен имени пользователя в базе. Если ваша консоль открыта под пользователем pavel - то поэтому вы авторизацию и проходите.

Отдельно про sudo - postgresql не обращает на сам sudo внимания. Если у вас в базе нет учётной записи root, то рут и не пройдёт авторизацию даже не смотря на то, что это рут. Аналогично если в hg_hba для unix-сокета сделать md5 авторизацию вместо peer, то пароль будет требоваться и для postgres пользователя в том числе при заходе через `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`.

Следующая строка

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Для соединений по tcp/ip через loopback уже указана как md5 - т.е. сервер требует от клиента прислать хэшированный пароль (от чего именно хэш помимо пароля не помню). Таким образом, если вы попробуете сделать

```
psql -U pavel -h 127.0.0.1 postgres
```

То пароль будет запрошен.